# 10 days in France - a trip from Amsterdam: is it worth buying an InterRail card?

Tags: trains, tickets, france, amsterdam, interrail

I'm planing a 10 days InterRail trip in France, and I've summed up all point-to-point trains costs = 200 euro.

In addition there are the international trains to go and come from Amsterdam (my hometown city), approximately 220 euros.

So, total costs would be 420 euros.

A France InterRail card seems not be convenient ([319 euros for 8 days trips in a month](http://www.interrailnet.com/interrail-passes/one-country-pass/france)), unless it covers the trips from and to Amsterdam. Which I suspect it doesn't, or are the international trips partially covered on national ground ?

Also, is there an InterRail pass for France + Benelux ? In that case I could cover the entire trip.

Any tip is welcome.

Comment: It looks like there is a France+Benelux, but it's not for sale within Europe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you considered the Belgian [Rail-pass](http://www.b-rail.be/nat/E/tarifs/passes/rail/index.php) or  [Go-pass](http://www.b-rail.be/nat/E/tarifs/tickets/gopass1/index.php)? It is a really affordable formula to travel through Belgium. For less then 8 Euro (depends on your age) you can travel through all of Belgium. With this card a Interrail for only France might suffice.

A disadvantage of both passes is that you need to buy them in Belgium at the station

Comment: Buying tickets in a station in belgium is quite a big issue, making my trip complicated, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

You used to get a discounted ticket to your interrail region as part of your interrail card. Can't say whether that's still the case.

However, your estimate of 220 euros to get to and from France from Amsterdam sounds unlikely. A roundtrip Amsterdam-Paris can be had for as little as 70 euros (http://www.nshispeed.nl/).

Also, at 320 euros for just 8 days, depending on where you plan to go, it sounds like the cost might not justify getting it. But that depends heavily on where you plan to go.

Comment: -1 for calling the estimate unlikely. I just checked you link and the first result, returns even 240 Euro for a return. The 70 eure fee is a joke. True they have the fee available, but good luck in obtaining it

Comment: A joke? That's rather harsh. I suppose it depends on when you checked the fare for. I did a search for leaving 25 July, returning on 17 August and there are several connections at 70 euros available for those dates. But, sure, more expensive tickets are also available.

Comment: MastaBaba @Andra Thanks, you gave me an idea of the range of prices. Indeed I can't pick any day or any time, but I need to fit the trains timetables with my trip

Comment: Mastababa, I wrote 220 euros for national trains, not 320. I'm visiting 7 cities in the south of france. In any case, even if the interrail card is providing a discount on the international trip (which I assume not to be more than 50%), it doesn't seem to me to be convenient in my case. Especially because tgv reservations still need to be made together with the inter rail card, and they are an additional cost. Do you confirm ?

Comment: The 320 I mentioned is the cost of the 8 day interrail card for France (which is really 319, but, hey :). But what I think you're saying is correct. That is, interrail doesn't appear the best option. There are roundtrip tickets to the south of France for 60 euros each way, which is a steal, though connections might be harder to find at these discounted prices for the deep south than they are for Paris. Also keep in mind that you can fly Eindhoven - Carcassonne, very much the deep south, with Ryanair for under 40 euros, all-in, if you book enough in advance.

Comment: It's not always so expensive but it's pretty common so either way, 220 € is not “unlikely”.